# load image through javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am creating a social website.I want to show all the details of registered users from the database in a list which includes their image and name.I want to display an image if the user has not provided the image.If the image has been provided by the user,sometimes it may get lost from database.At that time also i need to display a particular image.I have found that by using javascript method `onerror()`,we can check whether the image is loaded or not.I am unaware of its implementation.

My code sample is like this:

```
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($result_personal))
{
$row_photo = $row_data['acnt_profile_picture'];  
<div class="feedstory" id="feedstory">
 <img src="<?php if($row_photo!=NULL){echo $row_photo;}
 else{?>images/no_image.png<?php }?>" id="image1" width="34" height="34" align="left" class="feedthumb" alt="photo" 
 onerror="imageError()"/>
</div>
}
```

My javscript method is like this:

```
 function imageError()
 {
 document.getElementById("image1").src="images/no_image.png";
 }
```

I need to display `no_image.png` if `$row_photo` is null or `$row_photo` is not loaded

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: 'sometimes it may get lost from database' Losing your user data is NOT ACCEPTABLE in any way. So find out WHY this is disappearing.

Comment: @ToonCasteele I want to load the "no_image.png" if the $row_photo is not loaded.It is not happening in my case.I think the error is in the javascript method

Comment: give the full path of the image.

Comment: if $row_photo is null display default image or ur no_image.png which i guess can be modified inside the while loop

Comment: @AmazingDreams Ya,I know that.I have deleted the value from the database in my case here.

Comment: Have you checked if your image path is correct in firebug (or something else)

Comment: @ToonCasteele if the variable is null,"no_image.png" is displaying.Bit if the image is not loaded,"no_image.png" is not been displayed

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Your `imageError` function is fine, provided A) You actually have an `img` element with the `id` `"image1"` (you haven't shown one), and B) The path `images/no_image.png` resolves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said (in the comments)

> if the variable is null,"no_image.png" is displaying.Bit if the image is not loaded,"no_image.png" is not been displayed

So it's not a path issue, there's something wrong with the `imageError` call.

The call would be right **if** you had an `img` element with the `id` `"image1"`. But your `img` element doesn't have that `id`, and you haven't shown a different one that does.

If your goal is to show `no_image.png` in the `img` element that had the error, then:

Change your `onerror` attribute from:

```
onerror="imageError()"
```

to

```
onerror="imageError(this)"
```

And then change `imageError` to:

```
function imageError(img)
{
    img.src="images/no_image.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enclose your php code in php tags.

jQuery solution:

```
<?php
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($result_personal)) {
    $row_photo = $row_data['acnt_profile_picture'];
?>
    <div class="feedstory" id="feedstory">
         <img src="<?php echo $row_photo ?>" width="34" height="34" align="left" class="feedthumb" alt="photo" />
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('img').error(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            src: '/images/missing-image.jpg',
            alt: 'Sorry! This image is not available!',
            style:'border: 1px solid #f00;'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not your database structure is the same as mine, you can use this function, I put it inside my User class.

```
public static function ProfileImage($user_ID, $image_ID, $size)
{
    global $http_r;

    $image_URL;
    if($image_ID != null)
        $image_URL = $http_r ."/userfiles/images/". $user_ID ."/thumbnails/". $image_ID .".jpeg";
    else
        $image_URL = $http_r ."/template/images/noprofilepic.jpg";

    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_URL; ?>" class="profile-<?php echo $size; ?>">
    <?php
}
```

Which is then used like the following: `User::ProfileImage($user_ID, $image_ID, "small");`

But, I have a seperate table for my images and I do not store image paths directly.

Comment: I have to add I want to hash `$image_ID` and `$user_ID` so that some asses cannot simply 'scroll' through my users' images.